# Suppress noise on digital signal

Tags: filter, opto-isolator, low-pass

Tasked with improving on an existing design, I need to read pulses using a reed sensor excited with a magnet, placed on the front wheels of motorbikes.

The system's core has changed, moving from a PIC microcontroller to a NXP i.MX6 microprocessor.

Based on my predecessor's design, I came up with solution A, filtering; in a brief talk, it came out how it took several attempts to design the correct filter, as older bikes bear different type of noise, due to different ignitions, alternators, rectifiers and whatnot; in extreme cases, accelerating while the bike was standing would result in the uC picking up some noise interpreted as a change in logic level, and counted accordingly as one revolution of the wheel.

In other projects I have successfully used opto isolators, and while reviewing the final design, I came up with solution B, that would cost me one extra component type in the BOM.

[image: the two circuits I have designed]

My reasoning:

A) 2nd order low pass filter is ok as long as I keep cutoff frequency as low as possible, to keep the most possible noise out; should I decide to reuse the same board for a different project, I'd need to change L9 and C48 according to the new frequency.

B) maximum input frequency is dictated by the chosen opto, to change the maximum frequency I'd need to find one with the same footprint, but **I think this would result in overall better signal quality to the microprocessor, while also protecting the GPIOs from harm. Is this assumption correct?**

Answer (score 1):

Solution B doesn't really do much.

You have both sides connected to the same ground, so it isn't really isolating.

If it is removing glitches, then it is because of some side effect of the opto-isolator.  If you change opto-isolators or the noise source changes, then noise may get through again and you won't have many options to fix the problem.

I'd stick with option A.  You have control over how the noise is removed, and can adjust it if needed.

---

I'm not real good with LC filters, but running your values through an online calculator says the cutoff is at like 80kHz.

If that's the real cutoff, then that's crazy high for counting wheel RPM. That'd be like 5 million RPM or something.

---

I gave it some more thought, and I think I'd try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDaOeC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Circuit B has a couple of things going for it, that have nothing to do with the frequency of the signal or the optoisolator function.

1. Low impedance.  Both ends of the reed switch have a relatively low resistance path to either +5V or ground.  That makes it harder for interference to influence the circuit.
2. Not using the chassis ground.  Garbage on the ground is probably a part of your problems.

The circuit I drew is low impedance.  It switches 5V through the reed switch, and doesn't touch the chassis ground.

Since the optoisolator in your circuit wasn't really isolating, I left it out.  A transistor does the job just as well.

1. R4 limits the current so that nothing burns out if the cable to the reed switch gets crushed to ground.
2. R2 limits the current to the base of Q1 - it also protects Q1 in case something outside gets shorted to the input.
3. R3 pulls the base of Q1 down to make sure it is really off when it is supposed to be off.
4. C2 might not be needed.  I put it there in case you get high voltage spikes coming in from the reed switch line - like, laying the wires too close to the spark plug wires.
5. C1 is there as a filter and to catch the high voltage stuff from the spark plugs (same as C2).
6. The "cutoff" frequency of the filter formed by R2 and C1 is much lower than you were using - it is also a much weaker filter.  I think it will be adequate.

You could connect R1 to +3.3V instead of +5V if that's what your processor GPIO needs.

Comment: Isn't the diode of the opto suppressing al the noise that could be induced in the wire, up to its Vthresh?
It also uses a different power source, and i don't have the GND wire going down the fork, acting as antenna, this way i should avoid ground bouncing.
(cutoff freq. is indeed 80kHz, values were given to me after testing)

Comment: Any noise lower than the LED Vf in the optocouple shouldn't bother you anyway.  That's around 1.2V for the infrared LEDs used in optocouplers.

Comment: With this schematic i see similar issue to what brought me to consider opto: any noise shouldn't have enough Power to drive the LED of the opto, but, as it could be strong enough to be picked up as a hi level by μP GPIO for long enough to generate interrupt, it could as well be strong enough to drive base of Q3 (for which i see you used both strong pull down R3 and high base resistance R2). Couldn't I just use extra strong pull up in sol.A, like R69 = 500Ω? I'm worried for long wire acting as antenna, from device to fork.

Answer (score 0):

Because both sides of the opto share a common GND, it is not addressing one of the most common noise sources.  However, it does add something to the circuit.  Basically, it is functioning as a comparator without hysteresis.  And, significantly, without debounce.  You can debounce the switch signal in software, but you have not stated that this is being done.  As shown, you will have to flip the logic polarity in software because the opto is configured as an inverter.

Suggestion:  Move R1 to the +5 V side of the switch, and connect the U1 anode directly to the switch output.  This limits the short circuit current if there is a wiring fault from either side of the cable to the frame.

Suggestion:  Configure the opto output as an emitter follower.  This preserves the input logic polarity, and the output now is equivalent to the original circuit.  Also, you can add a resistor from U1 pin 7 to pin 1 for some hysteresis.

Comment: You are right, i'm missing the debounce cap, thanks

Comment: Signal polarity is not an issue, as i can interrupt om both rising and falling edge

Answer (score -1):

A) You are correct.
B) Yet again correct.
My preference would be the optocoupler. Although it adds an extra component to the BOM, the overal component count is lower.
The issue with having to choose a potiential different optocoupler for a different frequency should not be a big issue. Many optocouplers (as far a quick browse showed me) use the same pinout. The footprint might be a small issue, but you can combat this by making a double footprint. Where you have lets say 8 pads instead of 4. Where 4 are in the package size SO4, and the other 4 in package size SOP4.